# New Session login details

Tags: php

This script works brilliantly, so thanks for that! I am very new to PHP and I would like to carry the login username into the next and subsequent pages. I have tried the code below which works with simple login scripts, but not with this one I must be missing something. If anyone could point me in the right direction would be very grateful. Thanks:

```
<?php 
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 


if (isset($_SESSION['username'])
{

    echo "You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<p>";

    echo "<a href='logout.php'> Click here to logout<a/>";
    }

else

header ("Location: form.php");

?>
```

Comment: Which script are you referring to?

Comment: Code for the new login script?

Comment: If you are making Login I think it's better to use `session` to keep the user login.

Comment: Here is the link to the script in stackoverfow; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798002/php-help-redirecting-a-user-based-on-url-redirect-in-database

Answer (score 0):

consider you have a login field `loginTxt` and a password field `passwordTxt`.

in all your pages, you should have a `session_start()` declaration.
then, you post to a login.php script.

if your login.php script, you have to verify that this is the correct username (admin) or password (123456).

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['loginTxt']) && isset($_POST['passwordTxt'])&& $_POST['loginTxt'] == "admin" && $_POST['passwordTxt'] == "123456"){
    $_SESSION['connected']=true;
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Then, you have to verify if user is connected and to redirect him, if he is not loggued, for all pages of your site:

```
session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['connected']) || $_SESSION['connected']!== true){ 
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

You could implements database instead of using hardcoded login/password, but the principle is the same.